# Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" specs2 mocking a method that returns int

Tags: scala, mocking, sbt, specs2

I am using following configuration to run a test case using specs2 specification and specs2 mockito and mocked a method that is supposed to return int but it gives following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(Object, org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor, java.lang.reflect.Method, Object[], java.util.concurrent.Callable)" is null
```

Project configs.

```
Play Framework version: 2.8.19
scala version: 2.12.17
java version: 17
specs2-mock: 4.13.3
specs2-core: 4.13.3
scalacOptions:=Seq("-release", "17")
```

```
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

@Singleton
class Demo @Inject() (f: Calculator) {

  def run(pair: Pair): Int = {
    val p = f.calculate(pair)
    p+5
  }

}
----------------------
import com.google.inject.{ Inject, Singleton }


@Singleton
class Calculator @Inject() (p: Int){

  def calculate(pair: Pair): Int = {
    p + pair.a
  }

}

case class Pair(a: Int, b: String)
---------------------------------------

import org.specs2.matcher.ShouldThrownExpectations
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.Scope

class DemoTest extends Specification  {

  isolated

  "DemoTest.calculate" should {

    "return 5" in new Mocks {

      f.calculate(any[Pair]) returns 6
      val res = demo.run(Pair(1,"str"))
      res shouldEqual 11
    }

  }

}

trait Mocks extends Scope with Mockito with ShouldThrownExpectations{
  val f = mock[Calculator]
  val demo = new Demo(f)
}
```

I've been investigating the issue, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause here.

Comment: The code showed in the question doesn't compile. `Demo` class receives a `Calculator`, you are mocking a class `Calculate` instead of `Calculator`, an instance of `Demo` is being created with `calculate` as parameter which is not defined in the scope. Could you edit your post providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I tried to do a quick POC in my local using the libs with the version listed, with the compilation errors mentioned before fixed and same jdk and I was able to execute the test with no issues

Comment: I have updated the code exactly with annotations as well, you could have another look into it.

Comment: Another thing to attempt is to write the same kind of code, in Scala, but without the specs2-mock integration, by using the Mockito library directly

Comment: I run the test with the new code provided and I can't reproduce the error. Could be some issue in your configuration. Does this happen only in your local env? have you tried to execute this in another environment like another laptop, server or CI/CD pipeline? with the information shared is not possible to reproduce your issue. Can you add more info such as the command you are using to execute the tests, the configuration of your build tool to setup the project (based on the tags I guess you are using sbt), etc

Comment: I tried running it on server having CI/CD setup, it shows strange behaviour. I ran it for couple of times, few times it succeeded and few times failed. Same is happening now on my local as well. i am using `sbt test stage` , config `sbt 1.6.2 (Eclipse Adoptium Java 17.0.4.1)`